# Too many request from firebase authentication flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

After certain attempts am getting the exception of too many requests a device is blocked so is there any limit or time to cool down this time and get back to verification again from blocked? how much default time for this to resume the service?

Comment: It won't usually happen especially in Debug mode. Make sure you are calling the authentication function only once.

Comment: yes am calling once only but what will be the time to try again because not mentioned in firebase